# Unexpected operator error

Tags: bash, jar, find

What is wrong in my code?

```
#!/bin/sh

LOOK_FOR="$1"

for i in `find $2 -name "*jar"`; do
  echo "Looking in $i ..."
  #jar tvf $i | grep $LOOK_FOR > /dev/null
  jar tvf "$i" | grep "$LOOK_FOR" 

  if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
    echo "==> Found \"$LOOK_FOR\" in $i"
  fi  
done #line 13
```

Output

```
wk@wk-laptop:$ sh lookjar.sh org/apache/axis/message/addressing/EndpointReference  /media/0C06E20B06E1F61C/uengine/uengine
Looking in /media/0C06E20B06E1F61C/uengine/uengine/defaultcompany/build/uengine_settings.jar ...
[: 13: 1: unexpected operator
Looking in /media/0C06E20B06E1F61C/uengine/uengine/defaultcompany/WebContent/uengine-web/lib/FCKeditor/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload.jar ...
[: 13: 1: unexpected operator
Looking in /media/0C06E20B06E1F61C/uengine/uengine/defaultcompany/WebContent/uengine-web/lib/FCKeditor/WEB-INF/lib/FCKeditor-2.3.jar ...
[: 13: 1: unexpected operator
Looking in /media/0C06E20B06E1F61C/uengine/uengine/defaultcompany/WebContent/uengine-web/processmanager/signedmetaworks.jar ...
[: 13: 1: unexpected operator
Looking in /media/0C06E20B06E1F61C/uengine/uengine/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar ...
[: 13: 1: unexpected operator
Looking in /media/0C06E20B06E1F61C/uengine/uengine/hsqldb/lib/servlet.jar ...
[: 13: 1: unexpected operator
Looking in /media/0C06E20B06E1F61C/uengine/uengine/src/lib/commons-discovery.jar ...
[: 13: 1: unexpected operator
Looking in /media/0C06E20B06E1F61C/uengine/uengine/src/lib/google.jar ...
[: 13: 1: unexpected operator
Looking in /media/0C06E20B06E1F61C/uengine/uengine/src/lib/jxl.jar ...
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You need to use `=` instead of `==` in the `[ $? == 0 ]` line.

Comment: why whats the difference?

Comment: @kapitanluffy [Because the standard says so.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) It specifies what `=` does, but `==` is not mentioned at all and is thus invalid.

Comment: Oh, was confused since im seeing scripts that uses '==' instead of '='

Comment: `==` works for bash but for sh we need to use `=` to compare if two strings are equal or not.

Comment: so = works for both bash and sh? I thought sh and bash were the same?..!

Comment: @AlexanderMills sh is not the same as bash. sh is the [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell); its behaviour is specified in POSIX. [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) (Bourne again shell) is a GNU project that provides numerous extensions above and beyond what the standard Bourne shell provides. Clearly, it seems one of those extensions is allowing people to use `==` in its `test` builtin, something which is not standard and would not be tolerated by the standard Bourne shell.

Answer (score 8):

You should change that to:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ...
```

`-eq` does a numeric comparison.

You can also take advantage of the fact that in shell a return value of 0 is considered success and write your code like this:

```
if jar tvf "$i" | grep "$LOOK_FOR"; then
    ...
```

Comment: Well, numeric or string comparison doesn't really matter here.

Comment: Exactly my problem. `==` is only valid in **bash** but I was using **sh**.

Comment: sh is usually just a symlink to another interpreter. I was having the same problem as OP, and found on my Ubuntu install, sh pointed to dash, which I presume uses = to compare strings.

Comment: I also found that lbuntu uses dash as the default shell.

Comment: -eq: unexpected operator

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
LOOK_FOR="$1"    
find $2 -name "*jar"`| while read -r file
  echo "Looking in $file ..."
  jar tvf "$file" | grep "$LOOK_FOR" 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "==> Found \"$LOOK_FOR\" in $file"
  fi  
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    echo "==> Found \"$LOOK_FOR\" in $i"
fi
```

Comment: That's a bashism, and I know from the error message posted that the OP is not using bash. :-P

Comment: Startingly, some distro's have bash for their /bin/sh, FWIW.  In this case I think bash works with either `=` or `==` so it's probable the OP wasn't using bash (and only bash supports the `[[` style I think) FWIW.