# ZSH subString extraction

Tags: zsh

### Goal

In **ZSH** script, for a given args, I want to obtain the first string and the rest.

For instance, when the script is named `test`

```
sh test hello
```

supposed to extract `h` and `ello`.

### [ZSH manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/)

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/zsh_a4.pdf

says:

> Subscripting may also be performed on non-array values, in which case the subscripts specify a
>   substring to be extracted. For example, if FOO is set to ‘foobar’, then ‘echo $FOO[2,5]’ prints
>   ‘ooba’.

### Q1

So, I wrote a shell script in a file named `test`

```
echo $1
echo $1[1,1]
```

terminal:

```
$ sh test hello
hello
hello[1,1]
```

the result fails. What's wrong with the code?

### Q2

Also I don't know how to extract subString from n to the last. Perhaps do I have to use Array split by regex?

### EDIT: Q3

This may be another question, so if it's proper to start new Thread, I will do so.

Thanks to  @skishore Here is the further code

```
#! /bin/zsh

echo $1

ARG_FIRST=`echo $1 | cut -c1`
ARG_REST=`echo $1 | cut -c2-`
echo ARG_FIRST=$ARG_FIRST
echo ARG_REST=$ARG_REST

if $ARG_FIRST = ""; then
  echo nullArgs
else
  if $ARG_FIRST = "@"; then
    echo @Args
  else
    echo regularArgs
  fi
fi
```

I'm not sure how to compare string valuables to string, but for a given args `hello`

result:

```
command not found: h
```

What's wrong with the code?

### EDIT2:

What I've found right

```
#! /bin/zsh

echo $1

ARG_FIRST=`echo $1 | cut -c1`
ARG_REST=`echo $1 | cut -c2-`
echo ARG_FIRST=$ARG_FIRST
echo ARG_REST=$ARG_REST

if [ $ARG_FIRST ]; then
  if [ $ARG_FIRST = "@" ]; then
    echo @Args
  else
    echo regularArgs
  fi
else
  echo nullArgs
fi
```

### EDIT3:

As the result of whole, this is what I've done with this question.

#### https://github.com/kenokabe/GitSnapShot

**GitSnapShot** is a ZSH thin wrapper for Git commands for easier and simpler usage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the cut command:

```
echo $1 | cut -c1 
echo $1 | cut -c2-
```

Use `$()` to assign these values to variables:

```
ARG_FIRST=$(echo $1 | cut -c1)
ARG_REST=$(echo $1 | cut -c2-)
echo ARG_FIRST=$ARG_FIRST
echo ARG_REST=$ARG_REST
```

You can also replace `$()` with backticks, but the former is recommended and the latter is somewhat deprecated due to nesting issues.

Comment: Thanks @skishore, your code works, but how can I store the result to, say, argFirst and argRest?

Comment: Not sure how to format comments nicely, so I edited my answer.

Comment: eah, I just did without quotation.. Works perfect. You are cool. Thank  s a lot!

Comment: I have another quesion, and if you have a thought, plz let me know  @skishore

Comment: See here for how to compare strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-can-i-compare-strings-in-bash-script Basically the comparison lines should look like `if [[ "$ARG_FIRST" == "" ]]; then`

Comment: Thanks again @skishore , I sort of found the solution like that; please see my EDIT2:, it works with [ ... ], but you also suggest to use [[ ... ]], what is the difference, and my solution should be rather avoided??

Comment: The brackets just increase the allowable syntax within the clause (for example, they enable && and ||). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces

Comment: Ok, so for the single condition,  [[ ... ]] is extra and not required to use I understand. Am I correct here.

Answer (score 12):

### A1

As others have said, you need to wrap it in curly braces. Also, use a command interpreter (`#!`...), mark the file as executable, and call it directly.

```
#!/bin/zsh

echo $1
echo ${1[1,1]}
```

### A2

The easiest way to extract a substring from a parameter (zsh calls variables parameters) is to use parameter expansion. Using the square brackets tells zsh to treat the scalar (i.e. string) parameter as an array. For a single character, this makes sense. For the rest of the string, you can use the simpler `${parameter:start:length}` notation instead. If you omit the `:length` part (as we will here), then it will give you the rest of the scalar.

File `test`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

echo ${1[1]}
echo ${1:1}
```

Terminal:

```
$ ./test Hello
H
ello
```

### A3

As others have said, you need (preferably double) square brackets to test. Also, to [test if a string](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) is *NULL* use `-z`, and to test if it is not *NULL* use `-n`. You can just put a string in double brackets (`[[ ... ]]`), but it is preferable to make your intentions clear with `-n`.

```
if [[ -z "${ARG_FIRST}" ]]; then
  ...
fi
```

Also remove the space between `#!` and `/bin/zsh`.
And if you are checking for equality, use `==`; if you are assigning a value, use `=`.

### RE:EDIT2:

- Declare all parameters to set the scope. If you do not, you may clobber or use a parameter inherited from the shell, which may cause unexpected behavior. Google's shell [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html) is a good resource for stuff like this.
- Use builtins over external commands.
- Avoid backticks. Use `$(...)` instead.
- Use single quotes when quoting a literal string. This prevents pattern matching.
- Make use of `elif` or `case` to avoid nested `if`s. `case` will be easier to read in your example here, but `elif` will probably be better for your actual code.

Using `case`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

typeset ARG_FIRST="${1[1]}"
typeset ARG_REST="${1:1}"

echo $1
echo 'ARG_FIRST='"${ARG_FIRST}"
echo 'ARG_REST='"${ARG_REST}"

case "${ARG_FIRST}" in
  ('') echo 'nullArgs' ;;
  ('@') echo '@Args' ;;
  (*)
    # Recommended formatting example with more than 1 sloc
    echo 'regularArgs'
    ;;
esac
```

using `elif`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

typeset ARG_FIRST="${1[1]}"
typeset ARG_REST="${1:1}"

echo $1
echo 'ARG_FIRST='"${ARG_FIRST}"
echo 'ARG_REST='"${ARG_REST}"

if [[ -z "${ARG_FIRST}" ]]; then
  echo nullArgs
elif [[ '@' == "${ARG_FIRST}" ]]; then
  echo @Args
else
  echo regularArgs
fi
```

### RE:EDIT3

- Use `"$@"` unless you really know what you are doing. [Explanation](https://web.archive.org/web/20180304040449/http://zshwiki.org/home/scripting/args).

Comment: Excellent answer . It not only answers the OP's question, but it also provides many good insights for how to improve coding in shell.

Answer (score 7):

> So, I wrote a shell script in a file named test

```
$ sh test hello
```

This isn't a `zsh` script: you're calling it with `sh`, [which is (almost certainly) `bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sh). If you've got the shebang (`#!/bin/zsh`), you can make it executable (`chmod +x <script>`) and run it: `./script`. Alternatively, you can run it with `zsh <script>`.

> the result fails. What's wrong with the code?

You can wrap in braces:

```
echo ${1}        # This'll work with or without the braces.
echo ${1[3,5]}   # This works in the braces. 
echo $1[3,5]     # This doesn't work.
```

Running this: `./test-script hello` gives:

```
./test-script.zsh hello 
hello
llo
./test-script.zsh:5: no matches found: hello[3,5]
```

> Also I don't know how to extract subString from n to the last. Perhaps do I have to use Array split by regex?

Use the `[n,last]` notation, but wrap in braces. We can determine how long our variable is with, then use the length:

```
# Store the length of $1 in LENGTH. 
LENGTH=${#1}
echo ${1[2,${LENGTH}]}  # Display from `2` to `LENGTH`.
```

This'll produce `ello` (prints from the 2nd to the last character of `hello`).

Script to play with:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh

echo ${1}      # Print the input
echo ${1[3,5]} # Print from 3rd->5th characters of input
LENGTH=${#1}   
echo ${1[2,${LENGTH}]} # Print from 2nd -> last characters of input.
```

> You can use the cut command:

But that would be using extra baggage - `zsh` is quite capable of doing all this on it's own without spawning multiple sub-shells for simplistic operations.

Comment: Debian & Ubuntu nowadays have `sh` link to the more minimal `dash` (not not `bash` as stated above). (See: [Dash as /bin/sh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh))

Comment: You don't need the `LENGTH` thing, you can just use `-1` instead. As in `${1[2;-1]}`