# Printing a string value in awk results in error

Tags: awk

```
fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
    `%s SPT=80'
     ^ ran out for this one
```

This my code

```
for ((h = 1 ; h < 4 ; h++ )); do 
    x=$(awk -v i=h -v j=17 'FNR == 2 {printf "%s " $j}' newiptables.log)
        echo $x
```

This is my file

```
Dec 26 09:17:51 localhost kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:10:c6:a8:da:68:00:90:7f:9c:50:5a:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.16 DST=10.128.1.225 LEN=313 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=59334 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=56506 WINDOW=46535 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Dec 26 09:17:52 localhost kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:10:c6:a8:da:68:00:90:7f:9c:50:5a:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.16 DST=10.128.1.225 LEN=1440 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47303 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=56506 WINDOW=46535 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Dec 26 09:17:52 localhost kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:10:c6:a8:da:68:00:90:7f:9c:50:5a:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.16 DST=10.128.1.225 LEN=1440 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47559 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=56506 WINDOW=46535 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

Comment: Closely related questions:
[SO 20742474](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742474),
[SO 20780315](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780315),
[SO 20780890](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780890),
[SO 20781258](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781258).
Not quite duplicates, but the same data stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a missing comma in the `printf` command for `awk`:

```
awk -v i=h -v j=17 'FNR == 2 {printf "%s ", $j}' newiptables.log
                                          ^
                                          |== This is needed
```

Quoting from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html#Basic-Printf):

> A simple `printf` statement looks like this:
>
> ```
>  printf format, item1, item2, ...
> ```