# Printing a string value results not found

Tags: bash, awk

When I run my script, there is no output to the terminal.

This my code:

```
for ((h = 1 ; h < 4 ; h++ )); do 
    x=$(awk -v i=h -v j=17 'FNR == i {printf "%s ", $j}' newiptables.log)
        echo $x
done
```

This is the file

```
Dec 26 09:17:51 localhost kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:10:c6:a8:da:68:00:90:7f:9c:50:5a:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.16 DST=10.128.1.225 LEN=313 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=59334 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=56506 WINDOW=46535 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Dec 26 09:17:52 localhost kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:10:c6:a8:da:68:00:90:7f:9c:50:5a:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.16 DST=10.128.1.225 LEN=1440 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47303 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=56506 WINDOW=46535 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Dec 26 09:17:52 localhost kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:10:c6:a8:da:68:00:90:7f:9c:50:5a:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.16 DST=10.128.1.225 LEN=1440 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47559 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=56506 WINDOW=46535 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `i=$h` when invoking your awk script?

Comment: Are you sure? It outputs `SPT=80` three times for me.

Comment: sorry i've made a mistake

Comment: Closely related questions:
[SO 20742474](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742474),
[SO 20780315](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780315),
[SO 20780890](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780890),
[SO 20781258](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781258).
Not quite duplicates, but the same data stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying:

```
awk -v i=h -v j=17 ...
```

Note `i=h` which is equivalent to saying: `i=0`.

It seems that you wanted to say:

```
x=$(awk -v i=$h -v j=17 'FNR == i {printf "%s ", $j}' newiptables.log)
             ^
             |== refer to the variable h
```