# String comparison not Working properly

Tags: linux, bash

My code:

```
x=$(awk -v i=$h -v j=17 'FNR == i {printf "%s ", $j}' newiptables.log)
s="SPT=80"
```

The log file referenced is:

```
Dec 26 09:17:51 localhost kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:10:c6:a8:da:68:00:90:7f:9c:50:5a:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.16 DST=10.128.1.225 LEN=313 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=59334 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=56506 WINDOW=46535 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Dec 26 09:17:52 localhost kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:10:c6:a8:da:68:00:90:7f:9c:50:5a:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.16 DST=10.128.1.225 LEN=1440 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47303 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=56506 WINDOW=46535 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Dec 26 09:17:52 localhost kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:10:c6:a8:da:68:00:90:7f:9c:50:5a:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.16 DST=10.128.1.225 LEN=1440 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47559 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=56506 WINDOW=46535 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

Then the next condition in the script needs to be checked is:

```
if [[ "$x" == "$s" ]]
then 
 < process if condition is true>
else
 < process if condition is false>
fi
```

The if condition is not working

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: sorry the if loop it's not work

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?  Extract the `SPT` argument?

Comment: There's no loop in the code you show (but maybe that's a typo; you mean the `if` condition, I think). There's also no space between the `if` and the `[[`; add one. You'll also stand a better chance of matching `SPT=80` if `s` spells `SPT` correctly.

Comment: i need to compare x and s variables

Comment: Closely related questions:
[SO 20742474](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742474),
[SO 20780315](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780315),
[SO 20780890](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780890),
[SO 20781258](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781258).
Not quite duplicates, but the same data stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessary fix:

```
s="SPT=80"   # Not STP=80
```

<sup>*This has since been fixed in the question.*</sup>

Probably necessary fix:

```
if [[ "$x" == "$s" ]]  # Space between if and [[ highly recommended
then : it matches
else : it does not match
fi
```

As noted in the comments, the use of `"%s "` with a trailing space in the `awk` script means that the trailing space is stored in `"$x"` and this will break the comparison with `"$s"`.

Comment: Have you echoed `$x` and `$s` to see what they contain?  If not, do so — or run the script using `bash -x script`. Note that the `echo` should delimit the variables: `echo "[$x]" "[$s]"` where the square brackets serve to mark the start and end of each variable.  It is quite possible that the trailing blank is causing the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Observe your `awk` command:

```
printf "%s ", $j
```

You print a trailing space due to which the test `if [[ "$x" == "$s" ]]` fails.

Eliminate the space from the `printf`:

```
printf "%s", $j
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the [binary operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) `=~` (depending upon your need, of course):

```
if [[ "$x" =~ "$s" ]]
```

Comment: Or, instead of `printf`, simply use `print $j`.