# Bash: if no match then execute command

Tags: bash, grep, command, match, pipe

I want to execute a command only if a file does not contain the search. The line I'm searching is the last line of the file. Here's what I have so far:

```
if tail -n 1 debug.txt | [[ $( grep -q -c pass ) -eq 0 ]]; then
   echo "pass"
else
   echo "fail"
fi
```

This code is outputting "pass" whether the file contains that string or not.

Maybe there is a much easier way to do this too.

Comment: The part after the pipe works fine on it's own so I'm thinking maybe I'm piping it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one-liner:

```
[[ $(tail -n 1 file) == *pass* ]] && echo "pass" || echo "fail"
```

which is the same as:

```
if [[ $(tail -n 1 file) == *pass* ]]; then
    echo "pass"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

For further info: [String contains in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229551/1983854)

---

If you want to check [exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2237103/1983854), then do `[ "$var" == "pass" ]` comparison:

```
[ "$(tail -n 1 a)" == "pass" ] && echo "pass" || echo "fail"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use awk:

```
if awk 'END { exit !/pass/ }' file; then
```

Answer (score 0):

`-q` prevents output to standard output; `-c` simply changes what `grep` writes to standard output, so it is still suppressed by `-q`. As a result, the command substitution produces an empty string in every situation, which (as an integer) is always equal to 0.

What you want is simply:

```
if tail -n 1 debug.txt | grep -q pass; then
   echo "pass"
else
   echo "fail"
fi
```