# String equality in Bash script

Tags: android, bash, shell

I want to simply test if an android device is rooted from a computer (for a root/backup/flash script).
So i have to test some locations for the su binary. Here is my code :

```
#!/bin/sh


#####################
## ROOT CHECK

SU_LOCATIONS="/system/bin/su /system/xbin/su"

check() {
    echo "Checking for SU binary…"
    for file in $SU_LOCATIONS
    do
        suFileResult=`$ADB shell "ls $file"`
        echo "suFileResult = $suFileResult"
        echo "file         = $file"
        if [ "$suFileResult" == "$file" ];
            then echo "Su trouvé à $suFileResult"
        fi
    done
    echo "$suFileResult" > tmpbak/suFil
}
```

The problem is that even if file == suFileResult, "if" return false. If i remove the spaces around ==, "if" will always return TRUE…

What am i doing wrong ? If you give an other way to test the file (and where), it would be perfect.

Thanks for your answers !

PS : the string could contain spaces here, such as :

```
/system/bin/su: No such file or directory
```

EDIT After answer :

By the way, i figured how to remove this annoying \r character : add

```
| tr -d '\r'
```

will remove this character in ALL the string (not only on the end). So in my case :

```
suFileResult=$(adb shell "[[ -e $file ]]; echo \$?;" | tr -d '\r')
```

Comment: Remove the semi-colon.

Comment: @323go Please, explain, why did you mark this question as duplicate of [“How to compare strings in Bash script”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash-script). They have nothing in common.

Answer (score -1):

By some weird reason `adb` returns strings with DOS line-ending (`\r\n`).

```
$ suFileResult="$(adb shell "ls $file")"
$ set | grep suFileResult
suFileResult=$'/system/bin/su\r'
```

So the proper condidtion statement may look like:

```
[[ $suFileResult == ${file}$'\r' ]]
```

Also, I should note that using `ls` for checking file existence is a quite odd approach, even though `adb` does not return an error code, you could print it to STDOUT:

```
suFileResult=$(adb shell "[[ -e $file ]]; echo \$?")
if [[ $suFileResult == $'0\r' ]]; then
    echo "Su trouvé à $file"
fi
```

Comment: Marvelous, it works ! I think adb works like that to be compatible with Windows… But they could have changed it for the Linux version :p

Comment: @Salamandar Maybe. Also, I should note that using `ls` for checking file existence is a quite odd approach. See the edited answer.

Comment: Well, oddly it doesn't work : I have suFileResult to 0 even if the file doesn't exist.
That's strange because when i "chroot" on the phone, i correctly have 1 or 0 depending of the existance of the file.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape the `$?`. Fixed.

Comment: Ah yeah :)
Thanks, i just began shell scripting (though i used the cli for years) and it's a pretty difficult language… ^^''

Comment: @Salamandar Then as a matter for off-topic I shall turn your attention to the fact that what you’d written is not a GNU Bash script but generic POSIX shell script – yes, the hashbang – `#!/bin/sh` – it may point to Bash in your GNU distribution, but most probably it does not. You have to write `#!/bin/bash` if you want to use full feature Bash interpreter.

Comment: Yeah, for the moment I just use sh. Didn't have any problems until now, maybe sh actually points to bash when executing a script. I'll see if I need bash.