# Bash: count the occurrence of a string within a sentence

Tags: string, bash

I just wanted to count the occurrence of a particular string. This is my code:

```
count=0
output="hai how are you ? my-code is incorrect. Do you have a new my-code ?"
echo $output

for word in $output
do
    if ["$word" == "my-code"];then
        count=$((count + 1))
    fi
done

echo $count
```

Sadly, this is my output :

```
hai how are you ? my-code is incorrect. Do you have a new my-code ?
./test.sh: line 7: [hai: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [how: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [are: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [you: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [?: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [my-code: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [is: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [incorrect.: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [Do: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [you: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [have: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [a: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [new: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [my-code: command not found
./test.sh: line 7: [?: command not found
0
```

I am getting error at the string comparison step. I just searched and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash-script). I believe I have done the same. What's the bug here?

Comment: `grep -o 'my-code' input.txt | wc -l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` is an ordinary shell command. Like all commands, you need to put a space between the command name and the arguments:

```
if [ "$word" == my-code ]; then
```

It also requires that `]` be a separate argument so that it will ignore it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your have many syntax errors like spaces after `[` and before `]` and around `==` etc..

However you can avoid a loop by using `tr` to get your job done:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$output" | grep -c 'my-code'
2
```