# How to get the current git branch in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that should fail out if the current git branch doesn't match a pre-defined value.

```
if $gitBranch != 'my-branch'; then
   echo 'fail'
   exit 1
fi
```

Unfortunately, my shell scripting skills are not up to scratch: How do I get the current git branch in my variable?

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but it's certainly not a duplicate of the question linked.

Comment: For the posterity, my suggested duplicate was: [How to compare strings in Bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2237080/1983854), since it looks like the thing is missing here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the name of the current branch: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

So, to check:

```
if test "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" != my-branch; then
  echo Current branch is not my-branch >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Yup, although does anybody really use `test` rather than `[`?  I would suggest 

`if [ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" != 'my-branch' ] ;`

Comment: I may be the only one that prefers `test`, but I strongly suggest against `[`.  The amount of confusion caused by people thinking that `[` is a part of the grammar of the shell is very high.  Using `test` makes it much clearer that it is a command.  And who wants to have a final argument of `]`?  That's just weird.

Comment: Sure, it causes confusion -- but you only have to learn it once.

Comment: This fails in detached state.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the branch using `git branch` and a regex:

```
$gitBranch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
```

After that you just have to make your test.

Comment: The `sed` command can be written more simply as `sed -n '/^\* /s///p'`.

Comment: @Keith You're right. I got this snippet from somewhere on the internet and as it worked I never tried to improve it but your simplification totally works.