# Bash - How to make the loop run only once?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Whenever files in `count` directory changes, I need to calculate the `total count` and if the `total count` is between 50 and 100, I need to run a script with input `N` - which takes only 1 sec to run.

The problem is when the `total count` increases each time from 50 to 100, the script is executing each time. Is there a way to stop the loop/script from running the second time?

```
while inotifywait -r -e modify $dir
do

line=$(grep -ho '[0-9]*' /var/count* | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}')

echo "********** count is $line **********"

if [ $line -ge 50 ] && [ $line -lt 100 ]
then
echo "_____________executing if 1 _______________"
export N=1
/var/test.sh
fi

if [ $line -ge 100 ] && [ $line -lt 150 ]
then
echo "_____________executing if 2 _______________"
export N=2
/var/test.sh
fi
done
```

Comment: Check your variable `$N` to see if you've already executed it?

Comment: I am not sure.. How do I check if the variable `$N` as 1 is already executed?

Comment: [How to check if a variable is equal to a value in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you have two "done" statements.

I am having a difficult time following the problem. Is this what you want?  Each "if" will only execute once

```
export N=0
while inotifywait -r -e modify $dir
do
   line=$(grep -ho '[0-9]*' /var/count* | wc -l)
   if [ $N -lt 1 -a $line -ge 50 -a $line -lt 100 ]
   then
       export N=1
       /var/test.sh

   elif [ $N -lt 2 -a $line -ge 100 -a $line -lt 150 ]
   then
       export N=2
       /var/test.sh
   fi
done
```

Adjust code for the behavior you desire.

Comment: The OP probably wants a sleep somewhere.

Comment: "Done is only once" I modified the code. Thank You very much!!! Your solution worked perfectly for me. I was struggling with how to control $N. Thanks again :)