# Bash - Read from crontab -l in an if statement

Tags: bash, ubuntu, if-statement, cron

I'm trying to read the output from `crontab -l` to verify that the cronjob got added correctly.

Output of `crontab -l` right now is:

`0 */3 * * * ~/scripts/snapshot.sh` (which is what it should be).

My script to check is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

if `crontab -l` = "0 */3 * * * ~/scripts/snapshot.sh"; then
       echo "Done creating a cronjob"
else
       echo "NOTICE: Failed creating a crontab"
fi
```

I've tried multiple ways and none worked, if I do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
croncheck=`crontab -l`

echo $croncheck

#or
#echo `crontab -l`
```

The output shows this:

`0 */3 cronjobs scripts test.sh cronjobs scripts test.sh cronjobs scripts test.sh ~/scripts/snapshot.sh`

Instead of what it should show (what it should be).

Comment: * is expanding to file names

Comment: So how would I be able to get it to work? Can you please help?

Comment: and "=" is a bit less then I expect for string compare. You could single-quote the compare string, but I would suggest writing a regexp to check. For bash string compare my first hit was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash-script

Comment: `if [ -z \`crontab -l | grep '^0 \*/3 \* \* \* ~/scripts/snapshot.sh' \` ]; then ...  ` since everything in your version breaks if you need another cronjob.

Comment: flaschenpost, could you put that as an answer so I can mark is as answered? Thank you again!

Comment: Enclose the expected output in single quotes (`'`) to avoid the shell expand the asterisks (`*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would search with a regexp, but test it a bit if there is still some magic in the regexp. This could be also extended to match any valid time, not just the one you gave.

```
if [ -z "`crontab -l | grep '^0 \*/3 \* \* \* ~/scripts/snapshot.sh' `" ]; then
  echo "not found, something is wrong"
else
  echo "found, this is ok"
fi
```

Comment: By the way, your code works but it gives a small error before it echoes out the answer (only when it says found, this is ok). The error is `[: too many arguments`

Comment: ah, of course, i've missed the double quotes. `"\`crontab -l...\`"`