# grep: compare string from file with another string

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I have a list of files paths that I need to compare with a string:

```
git_root_path=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
list_of_files=.git/ForGeneratingSBConfigAlert.txt
cd $git_root_path
echo "These files needs new OSB config:"
while read -r line
do
    modfied="$line"
    echo "File for compare: $modfied"
        if grep -qf  $list_of_files" $modfied"; then
            echo "Found: $modfied"
        fi
done < <(git status -s | grep -v " M" | awk '{if ($1 == "M") print $2}')
```

$modified - is a string variable that stores path to file

Pattern file example:

```
SVCS/resources/
SVCS/bus/projects/busCallout/
SVCS/bus/projects/busconverter/
SVCS/bus/projects/Resources/  (ignore .jar)
SVCS/bus/projects/Teema/
SVCS/common/
SVCS/domain/
SVCS/techutil/src/
SVCS/tech/mds/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/tech/mds/exception/
SVCS/tech/mds/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/tech/mds/interfaces/
SVCS/app/cashmgmt/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/cashmgmt/exception/
SVCS/app/cashmgmt/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/cashmgmt/interfaces/
SVCS/app/customer/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/customer/exception/
SVCS/app/customer/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/customer/interfaces/
SVCS/app/etravel/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/etravel/exception/
SVCS/app/etravel/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/etravel/interfaces/
SVCS/app/hermes/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/hermes/exception/
SVCS/app/hermes/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/hermes/interfaces/
SVCS/app/journey/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/journey/exception/
SVCS/app/journey/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/journey/interfaces/
SVCS/app/offline/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/offline/exception/
SVCS/app/offline/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/offline/interfaces/
SVCS/app/order/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/order/exception/
SVCS/app/order/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/order/interfaces/
SVCS/app/payment/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/payment/exception/
SVCS/app/payment/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/payment/interfaces/
SVCS/app/price/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/price/exception/
SVCS/app/price/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/price/interfaces/
SVCS/app/product/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/product/exception/
SVCS/app/product/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/product/interfaces/
SVCS/app/railcar/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/railcar/exception/
SVCS/app/railcar/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/railcar/interfaces/
SVCS/app/reservation/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/reservation/exception/
SVCS/app/reservation/src/java/fi/vr/h/service/app/reservation/interfaces/
kraken_test.txt
namaker_test.txt
shmaker_test.txt
```

I need to compare file search pattern with a string, is it possible using grep?

Comment: Can you state in more detail what you expect? Do you want to look for a string in a list of files? Or compare a list of files with another list?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something, or is it simple string comparison you are after? In that case look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash-script

Comment: Do you want to grep the filename or do you need to look inside the file and do a grep on its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
git status -s | grep -v " M" | awk '{if ($1 == "M") print $2}' | \
grep --file=.git/ForGeneratingSBConfigAlert.txt --fixed-strings --line-regexp
```

- Piping the `awk` output directly to `grep` avoids the `while` loop entirely. In most cases you'll find you don't really need to print debug messages and the like in it.
- `--file` takes a file with one pattern to match per line.
- `--fixed-strings` avoids treating any characters in the patterns as special.
- `--line-regexp` anchors the patterns so that they only match if a *full* line of input matches one of the patterns.

All that said, could you clarify what you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The backslash isn't really necessary; a pipe at the end of line is enough to continue the pipeline on the next line.

Comment: @tripleee I generally treat that as an anti-pattern similar to not needing `?>` at the end of PHP files and the last `;` in JavaScript.

Comment: I just inserted your code and it works as I need it :D I only removed the `--line-regexp` as it is not needed in my situation. I was thinking in the box(inside while loop). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the overall logic, but a few immediate suggestions come to mind.

- You can avoid `grep | awk` in the vast majority of cases.
- A `while` loop with a `grep` on a line at a time inside the loop is an antipattern.  You probably just want to run one `grep` on the whole input.

Your question would still benefit from an explanation of what you are actually trying to accomplish.

```
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
git status -s | awk '!/ M/ && $1 == "M" { print $2 }' |
grep -Fxf .git/ForGeneratingSBConfigAlert.txt
```

I was trying to think of a way to add back your human-readable babble, but on second thought, this program is probably better without it.

The `-x` option to `grep` might be wrong, depending on what you are really hoping to accomplish.