# Get output of command; run another command if contains X

Tags: if-statement, command-line, command, bash

I want to **write a bash script that:**

1. Runs the command `bux`
2. - **a)** If the output of `bux` contains `have`, do nothing
   - **b)** If the output of `bux` contains `X`, run the command `Y`
   - **c)** If the output of `bux` contains `Z`, run the command `A`

- It will only contain *one* of these things, not multiple x

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  SO isn't a script writing service, though we're very willing to help with problems along the way.  You might also want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16263820/4687135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that should do what you want (provided that bux, Y and A are bash scripts) :

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=`source bux`
if [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ have ]]; then
   :
elif [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ X ]]; then
   source Y  
elif [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ Z ]]; then
   source A
fi
```

If you want to execute programs instead (provided that bux, Y and A are in the path) :

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=`bux`
if [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ have ]]; then
    :
elif [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ X ]]; then
    Y
elif [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ Z ]]; then
    A
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

glob patterns in a `case` statement like this:

```
case $(bux) in
    *have*)
        echo 'do nothing?'
        ;;
    *X*)
        Y
        ;;
    *Z*)
        A
        ;;
    *)
        echo 'default case.'  # display an error ...?
        ;;
esac
```

Obviously the patterns could be more complex if you like, but this seems to cover your requirements.

Comment: It should be `${bux}` or `$bux` (or, even better, `"$bux"`), but not `$(bux)`. Also, the patterns aren't regular expressions, just the "normal" pattern language of Bash, i.e., `*X*` instead of `.*X.*`

Comment: @BenjaminW. The OP needs to run the *command* `bux` and inspect its output so `$(bux)` is correct.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ooops, brain fart! The pattern point stands, though ;)

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the answer in accordance with the comments above.  Feel free to revert if you feel this is too intrusive; but the original answer didn't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Oh ! You're (obviously) right for the regex pattern, i'm too used to Perl style. Thanks for correcting that ;)