# Why is my "if" condition (string comparison) always true?

Tags: shell, if-statement

In the following example, I find that the `if [ $aaa==x ]` condition is always true.

```
for aaa in {x,y} 
do 
echo ---------
echo $aaa;
if [ $aaa==x ]
then echo this is x
elif [ $aaa==y ]
then echo this is y
fi
echo $aaa;
done;
```

That is, I always get the output as:

```
---------
x
this is x
x
---------
y
this is x
y
```

Even if I replace `==` with `=`, the problem remains. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare strings in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
if [ $aaa==x ]
```

You are expanding the parameter $aaa, then concatenating two `=` and the letter `x`, then testing whether this is a non-empty string (it always is).

```
if [ "$aaa" = x ]
```

Does what you want. Each part of the test should be passed as a separate argument, separated by whitespace.

Note that `==` isn't the standard syntax, you should use `=` to test whether two strings are equal.