# Bash Conditional Loop Issue Y or y ==> YES N or n==>NO

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, syntax, scripting

[image: ICode]

[image: Input & Output]

So the problem is i am not getting the desired output. Need some help in the problem statement as i am a newbie to the BashScript!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, you have to show us by posting samples into your post like what is working and what is not. If you say something is not working without showing us, we can't help on it, please do the needful in your post.

Comment: You should be using `=`. `-eq` is for comparing numbers, not strings.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475445/why-does-eq-show-non-numerical-strings-as-equal-in-bash

Comment: Since `[[` is for pattern matching, try:  `if [[ $input = [Yy] ]]`

Comment: Thanks it's done!!

Answer (score 1):

`-eq` is for *numeric* comparisons and all of the strings `YES`, `Y`, `N` and `NO` evaluate to zero. Hence they'll all match each other.

You should be using `=` rather than `-eq`.

However, you can also use regular expressions in `bash` with something like:

```
[[ $input =~ [Yy] ]]
```

That seems *much* more readable to me.

Comment: Or, since this is bash, `[[ ${input^} = Y ]]`