# Why does this *normal* string compare failed in bash?

Tags: bash, string-comparison

I have a string, like this:

`DayOfWeek=$(date +%A|tr -d '\n')
echo $DayOfWeek
Montag`

I wish to compare the result of the command with a string. Just like this:

`[ $DayOfWeek == "Monday" ] && echo True`

But the result was anytime false.

Here some more attempts:

`[ "$DayOfWeek" == "Monday" ] && echo True
[ $(date +%A|tr -d '\n') == "Monday" ] && echo True
[ $(date +%A|tr -d '\n') == "Monday" ] && echo True
[ $(date +%A|tr -d '\n') == 'Monday' ] && echo True
[ "$(printf "%s" "$DayOfWeek")" == "Monday" ] && echo True
[ "$(date +%A|tr -d '\n')" == 'Monday' ] && echo True
[[ $(date +%A|tr -d '\n') == 'Monday' ]] && echo True
[[ $(date +%A|tr -d '\n') == "Monday" ]] && echo True`

In the end following is working:

`[[ $(date +%A|tr -d '\n') == $(echo -n "Montag") ]] && echo True`

Can someone explain this behavior of bash to me? The used bash is version 4.4.19.

best regards,
akendo

Comment: Some comment to this: I assume at first, that the result wasn't stored as a string. I took a look at the [documentation for 'if' in bash](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html#sect_07_01_02_03). In the last line of the page, there is an quite similar example to mine approach. In the example they do quite the same, just using a `!=` instead of `==` so it should be remain a string, even when stored into a variable of bash?

Comment: `=` is the normal comparison operator for strings, not `==`. What are you  trying to do with that `tr`? It is not needed unless maybe you're messing with IFS?

Comment: Every single one of your attempts works for me (`bash 4.4.12`) - note your last example has `Montag` - this is a locale, not a bash issue...

Comment: I had this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2237103/997915) that seems to support my view. The `tr` will remove the newline, because I did assume that he would store it within the string and that was the reason for the failure.

Comment: I'm going to check the compre with one `=`.

Comment: Same result as with `==`. This makes sense, because in the official documentation of bash it is written as: `[ STRING1 == STRING2 ]`

Comment: `==` when using `[[ ]]`, but `=` when using `[ ]`.

Comment: `[ $DayOfWeek == "Monday" ]` is exactly the wrong way to quote.  The string `Monday` does not contain any variables and there is no need to protect it from interpolation.  Ignoring the question of `==` instead of `=`, it is better to write this as `[ "$DayOfWeek" = Monday ]`.  Since quotes seem to cause confusion, it would be preferred to write `[ "$DayOfWeek" = "Monday" ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the English word `Monday` in your attempts, but your working example uses `Montag`. I'm going to guess you're using a `DE` locale.

You can fix this by either using `Montag` in your comparison, or if you really need to use English words, do something like:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 date +%A
```

To force using an English locale.