# Bash - Breaking while loop with user input

Tags: linux, bash

I am total beginer with linux.

I have found that my question might be sloved already, but i cannot transfer answers to my example.

I am trying to make script which is asking user to provide folder name, then creates directory. After that, bash asks does user want to create next folder, if answer is different than yes, while loop should break.

I appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you in advance. 
My code: https://pastebin.com/xKNgV9gg

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Welcome in folder generator'
echo '#################################################'
echo '#################################################'

new_directory="yes"

while [ "$new_directory"=="yes" ]
do
    echo 'Give me folder name'
    read folderName
    mkdir $folderName
    echo "Would you like to create next folder ?"
    read $new_directory
done
```

Comment: copy your code in https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Add spaces around `==`.

Comment: Don't put `$` before the variable name in `read` command.

Comment: Quote your variables in case the folder name has spaces.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Bash is whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) separated.
2. `[ a = b ]` is not equal to `[ a=b ]`. The first compares string `'a'` with string `'b'`, the second check if the string `'a=b'` has non-zero length.
3. Always quote your variables, unless you know you don't have to.
4. Bash uses single `=` for string comparision. Double `==` is supported, but is not standard.
5. A good read can be found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Welcome in folder generator'
echo '#################################################'
echo '#################################################'

new_directory="yes"

while [ "$new_directory" == "yes" ]
do
    echo 'Give me folder name'
    read folderName
    mkdir "$folderName"
    echo "Would you like to create next folder ?"
    read new_directory
done
```

Comment: It still has errors and will not work as intended. Line 14 is buggy. Is all explained in shellcheck.net