# If - Compare two strings

Tags: string, bash, if-statement

I am trying to compare output of a command with a string.

```
# echo "$status"
Stateretired
# if [ "$status" == "Stateretired" ] ; then echo "Instance down"; else echo "Well nah"; fi
Well nah
#
```

#### Update:

Tried with single `=` but same results.

```
# echo "$status"
Stateretired

# if [ $status = "Stateretired" ] ; then  echo "Instance retired"; else  echo "Well nah"; fi
Well nah
```

#### Debug trace

With debug I saw a strange thing with comparison `'[' Stateretired == 'Stateretired' ']'`. Is it normal ? Hope its not.

```
++ grep State
++ sed -E 's/ +//g ; s/\|//g'
+ status='Stateretired'
+ echo 'Stateretired'
Stateretired
+ mystatus=Stateretired
+ '[' Stateretired == 'Stateretired' ']'
+ echo 'Instance not down'
Instance not down
```

#### color coding

In keep on debugging, I came to know that the color coding is causing this problem.

```
echo "$status" | tr -d '[:cntrl:]'
State[31mretired[0m
```

I am trying to find a way to remove them.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: [How to compare strings in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash)

Comment: I'm betting that your variable contains a whitespace or control character, such as a carriage return. What does `echo "[$status]"` print?

Comment: @ruakh, `echo "$status"
Stateretired` and `echo "[$status]"
[Stateretired]`

Comment: @ruakh: I assumed you retracted the close vote because OP's variable could have stray characters.

Comment: $status should be in double quotes "$status"

Comment: @Inian: I'm not quite sure how to interpret your comment; are you trying to ask why I reopened the question? If so, then: this OP was already correctly testing the strings for equality, so it didn't make sense to close this question as a dupe of one that gives only what (s)he already knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my output is in color, I tried with `tr` to confirm that.

```
echo "$status" | tr -d '[:cntrl:]'
State[31mretired[0m
```

And with search I came across a `sed` regex which will delete them
`sed -r 's/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,3}((;[0-9]{1,3})*)?)?[m|K]//g'`

Below is my debug trace

```
++ grep State
++ sed -E 's/ +//g ; s/\|//g'
+ status='Stateretired'
++ echo 'Stateretired'
++ sed -r 's/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,3}((;[0-9]{1,3})*)?)?[m|K]//g'
+ status=Stateretired
+ echo Stateretired
Stateretired
+ mystatus=Stateretired
+ '[' Stateretired == Stateretired ']'
+ echo 'Instance Down'
Instance Down
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As you found yourself, the control characters are making the strings different.
You can try to remove the control characters. Another approach is skipping them:

```
status="State[control characters]retired[more control characters]"
if [[ "${status}" =~ State.*retired ]]; then
   echo "Instance down"
else
   echo "Well nah"
fi
```

This solution will fail when the status can contain values like `State is not retired` or `Previous State was retired, now back to work`.

Comment: But your solution will work for `State[31mretired[0m1`  as well ?

Comment: It should work for `State[31mretired[0m1`, please test.

Answer (score 0):

You should use = instead of ==

This should work!

```
# echo "$status"
Stateretired
# if [ "$status" = "Stateretired" ] ; then echo "Instance down"; else echo "Well nah"; fi
#
```

Comment: Why? `man bash` lists both `string1 == string2` and `string1 = string2` as equal. Since his question is tagged as [tag:BASH], compatibility with other shells cannot be a valid reason unless stated explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly what color sequence to expect, then one option is to simply include it in the string you're comparing to:

```
if [ "$status" == $'State\x1B[31mretired\x1B[0m' ] ; then
```

where `$'...'` is a special quoting notation that supports backslash-escapes like `\n` and `\xHH` and so on; see [the *Bash Reference Manual*, §3.1.2.4 "ANSI-C Quoting"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) for more information.

That said, you might want to check the documentation of the command whose output you're capturing; it might support some options to make the output format more scripting-friendly.

Answer (score -1):

It is simple via:

```
test "a" = "a" && { echo "OK" ; }  || { echo "NO" ; }
```