# Variable comparison in bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I am trying to find out whether disk is SSD or HDD using bash script.

```
logical_name="/dev/sda"
type="" 
disk=$(basename $logical_name)
x=`cat $filename | grep "${disk}" | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ ! -z "$x" ]
then
        if [ "$x" = "0" ]
        then
                type="SSD"
        fi  
        if [ "$x" = "1" ]
        then
                type="HDD"
        fi  
fi

echo $type
```

Value of x is correct, 0 or 1. But after comparison, it's not assigning any value to variable `type`. It prints as empty. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here?

**More information:**

$filename is a file that contains output of `sudo lsblk  -d -o name,rota`

```
NAME ROTA
sda     1
sdd     1
sdc     0
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be "$x" == "0" instead of =?

Comment: @NirupIyer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2237103/2064607 I referred to this while writing code.

Comment: Though it's not a direct solution to your question, you could use `sed` to simplify this: `lsblk -d -o name,rota | sed -e 's/0$/SSD/g' -e 's/1$/HDD/g'`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here (despite there being some unnecessary checks). If `type` is empty at the end, that means the conditional has failed. Try `echo`ing the value of `x` just before first `if` condition (which seems redundant)

Comment: Please run  the script with `bash -x yourfile` and edit your post to include the debug log if the problem does not become immediately obvious

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't see any problem with the posted code, following would be a more simplified and maintainable version for doing the same.

```
DISK_NAMES=(SSD HDD)  # names are resolved by index

filename="in1.txt"
logical_name="/dev/sda"
disk="$(basename $logical_name)"
x="$(sed -n 's/'$disk' *\([0-9]*\)/\1/p' $filename)"
# check if $x is empty here, if required
echo "$x -> ${DISK_NAMES[$x]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `lsblk` command lets you specify a device, so you shouldn't have to `grep` through the `lsblk` output to find the device you're interested in. This also means you don't need the `name` column. Plus you can disable the header with `-n`, and the `-r` option (raw output) gets rid of the leading and trailing whitespace:

```
> hdtype() { lsblk -drno rota "$1" | sed 's/1/HDD/;s/0/SSD/'; }

> hdtype /dev/sda
HDD
```

As far as why your code isn't working, I'm not sure. It worked just fine in my bash terminal.