# Bash compare strings not working inside of while loop

Tags: bash, ash

I created this bash script and can't seem to figure out why my code inside of the if block isn't executing.

```
db_instances_status="creating" 
db_instances_status=$(makes api request to get value)

COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt 1 ]; do
  db_instances_status=$(makes api request to get value)

  echo "$db_instances_status" # echos available

  if [ "available" = "$db_instances_status" ]; then
     # code never makes it here
     dosomething()
     break;
  fi
  sleep 30
done
```

I followed examples from this [How to compare strings in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash)

and here https://tecadmin.net/tutorial/bash/examples/check-if-two-strings-are-equal/

Comment: Add a line above your `if` statement that says `db_instances_status='available'`. Now does your code enter the `if` section? If it does then `db_instances_status` does NOT just contain `available` in your surrounding code.

Comment: Try `echo "X${db_instances_status}X"` in case the status has leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: I get X"available"X

Comment: The issue was the actual value is quoted. "available"

Comment: Smh, it's always something minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either are not getting to the `if` statement or else the variable doesn't contain what you think it does.

This snippet will help debug both...

```
while [ $COUNTER -lt 1 ]; do
  echo "[DEBUG] getting status"
  db_instances_status=$(makes api request to get value)
  echo "[DEBUG] X${db_instances_status}X"
  echo "$db_instances_status" # echos available

  if [ "available" = "$db_instances_status" ]; then
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me debug. The actual value was being returned in quotes. it didn't execute because "available" doesn't equal available