# Beginning bash writer struggles with if test

Tags: bash, syntax

I have a rather simple bash script which is:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
source /reTech/REB3bastionscripts/setup/setenv.sh
echo "##### Begin check/create reportuser   #####################################################"
if [ $REPORT_DB_ENDPOINT != none ]; then
  user_exists=$(psql -U $REPORT_DB_USER -h $REPORT_DB_ENDPOINT -d $REPORT_DB -c "SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='reportuser'" | grep reportuser -c)
  if [ "$user_exists" == "1" ]; then
    echo Reportuser exists already in $REPORT_DB database. Resetting password and updating permissions...
  else
    echo creating user reportuser for $REPORT_DB
  fi
fi
if [ !$GRAFANA_DB_ENDPOINT != none ]; then
  user_exists=$(psql -U $GRAFANA_DB_USER -h $GRAFANA_DB_ENDPOINT -d $GRAFANA_DB -c "SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='reportuser'" | grep reportuser -c)
  if [ "$user_exists" == "1" ]; then
    echo Reportuser exists already in $GRAFANA_DB database. Resetting password and updating permissions...
  else
    echo creating user reportuser for $GRAFANA_DB
  fi
fi
echo "##### End check/create reportuser   #####################################################"
```

and no matter which permutations I try for the if statement, it always stops after showing what the value of the local variable user_exists contains but never executes the next step.
The result is:

```
##### Begin check/create reportuser   #####################################################
+ '[' psql-reb3az-devaz-reportdbserver.postgres.database.azure.com '!=' none ']'
++ grep reportuser -c
++ psql -U rebotics -h psql-reb3az-devaz-reportdbserver.postgres.database.azure.com -d report -c 'SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='\''reportuser'\'''
+ user_exists=0
```

I'm kindly asking for help here.
Thanks.
Wolfgang

Comment: Bash is a notoriously bad programming language. You won't be able to intuit / guess how to do things. Searching for specific Bash syntax will be much faster (and searching is a required first step before asking Stackoverflow). Review the duplicate question: [How to compare strings in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash)

Comment: I agree with you on searching before asking. Please grant that I did it and couldn't make sense of some of the answers, tried many, and still wasn't successful. That's why I asked. 
Anyhow, I wait until Monday when a kind soul from work might be inclined to help.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: The problem isn't the `if` statement, it's the `user_exists=$(psql ... | grep reportuser -c)` command before it combined with the `-e` option in the shebang. `grep` exits with a failure status if it doesn't find any matches, so `-e` treats that as an error and exits the script. You can add `|| true` to that command, or remove the `-e` option and add smarter error checking (it's pretty dumb; see [BashFAQ #105: "Why doesn't `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`, or `trap ERR`) do what I expected?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).)

Comment: It's terribly written anyway. You'd be better off with if psql ..blah | grep reportuser; then echo exists ; else ; echo creating ; fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-e` on the bash command line tells the shell to terminate when any command it executes exits with a non-zero value.

When the `grep ... -c` does not match `reportuser` it exits with a 1, so the shell stops running.  Note that for pipelines, only the last command's status is considered.

To fix, here are a couple of options:

- remove the `-e` from the shell (on the shebang, `#!`, line at the top)
- add `|| true` after the grep

Comment: A college of mine pointed the -e issue out and simply added a line before and after the section where I'm testing for existing users. The line before was "set +e" and the line after the section was "set -e:" . That was it. Also note that my posting was a simplified extraction from the whole script.

Comment: Sure, `set +e` ... `set -e` can be used to temporarily disable, then re-enable, that mode.  There are other ways as well...