# Cut column by column name in bash

Tags: bash

I want to specify a column by name (i.e. `102`), find the position of this column and then use something like `cut -5,7-` with the found position to delete the specified column.

This is my file header (`delim = "\t"`):

```
#CHROM  POS 1   100 101 102 103 107 108
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `for` loop in bash:

```
C=1; for i in $(head file -n 1) ; do if [ $i == "102" ] ; then break ; else C=$(( $C + 1 )) ; fi ; done ; echo $C
```

And a full script

```
C=1
for i in $(head in_file -n 1) ; do
    echo $i
    if [ $i == "102" ] ; then
        break ;
    else
        echo $C
        C=$(( $C + 1 ))
    fi
done
cut -f1-$(($C-1)),$(($C+1))- in_file
```

Comment: I think `$i == "102"` should be `$i = "102". `==` gives me an error like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011160/unexpected-operator-error

Comment: Correct, that's POSIX.

Comment: using bash, you can simply do (( C++ )) instead of C=$(( $C + 1 )), or even. echo $(( C++ )) as a single operation.

Comment: Is there a simple way to do this for more than one column?

Comment: With bash 4.x, yes, there is such a simple way -- you can create an associative array of column names to positions.

Comment: Why not ask `cut` to `--complement` your selection when you want to remove the columns rather than keep them?

Answer (score 2):

This awk should work:

```
awk -F'\t' -v c="102" 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==c){p=i; break}; next} {print $p}' file
```

Comment: OP wants to delete the column not print it.

Comment: It is difficult to understand the requirement without seeing expected output. `cut -d' ' -f1` command just prints single column usually.

Comment: This oneliner was very helpful to me, that wanted just to extract a field by name. Maybe somebody else on SO asked for a solution to this different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution without the restriction that only one column is to be removed. It is written as a bash function, where the first argument is the filename, and the remaining arguments are the columns to exclude.

```
rmcol() {
  local file=$1
  shift
  cut -f$(head -n1 "$file" | tr \\t \\n | grep -vFxn "${@/#/-e}" |
          cut -d: -f1 | paste -sd,) "$file"
}
```

If you want to select rather than exclude the named columns, then change `-vFxn` to `-Fxn`.

That almost certainly requires some sort of explanation. The first two lines of the function just removes the filename from the arguments and stores it for later use. The `cut` command will then select the appropriate columns; the column numbers are computed with the complicated pipeline which follows:

```
head -n1 "$file" |  # Take the first line of the file
tr \\t \\n       |  # Change all the tabs to newlines [ Note 1]
grep                # Select all lines (i.e. column names) which
     -v             #   don't match
       F            #   the literal string
        x           #   which is the complete line
         n          #   and include the line number in the output
     "${@/#/-e}" |  # Put -e at the beginning of each command line argument,
                    #   converting the arguments into grep pattern arguments (-e)
cut -d: -f1      |  # Select only the line number from that matches
paste -sd,          # Paste together all the line numbers, separated with commas.
```

Comment: Why not ask `cut` to `--complement` your selection when you want to remove the columns rather than keep them?

Comment: @DouwevanderLeest: that works, too, at least with Gnu cut. I don't think BSD cut has that option. But removing a `v` is pretty easy :-)

Answer (score 0):

trying a solution without looping through columns, I get:

```
#!/bin/bash
pick="$1"
titles="pos 1 100 102 105"

tmp=" $titles "
tmp="${tmp%% $pick* }"
tmp=($tmp)

echo "column ${#tmp[@]}"
```

It suffers from incorrectly reporting last column if column name can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small awk utility to cut specific headers - https://github.com/rohitprajapati/toyeca-cutter

Example usage -

awk -f toyeca-cutter.awk -v c="col1, col2, col3, col4" my_file.csv